# ng deploy to gh-pages: default page instead of app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my angular app on gh-pages using the angular-cli, but instead of my app (which actually works locally without hassle), I view the default angular-cli generated page. Do you have some suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that changing the `outputPath` in `angular.json` from `dist/<project>` to `dist` solved the issue.